# Impossible to replace content in tag <ul></ul>

Tags: regex, replace

I have html content like this

```
<div class='.desc_html_aff'>
sdsdfdfdgdsg
<ul class="pi_ul">
<li>abc</li>
<li>def </li>
<li>ererefe </li>
</ul>
wfwfwsfgdhfhfhdf
dgdfhfj
  </div>
```

I woudl like te replace content of `<ul>` by '!!'
here jquery which dont work

```
var desc_aff=$('.desc_html_aff').html().replace(/<ul(.*?)>(.*?)<\/ul>/gi,"!!")
```

I really cannot see what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?
Please help, thanks

Comment: Change `<div class='.desc_html_aff'>` to `<div class='desc_html_aff'>` (remove the dot)

Comment: @DenysSéguret ahh, yes of course. (FYI, dv wasn't me - even though I'm the only other active poster)

Comment: thanks Denys .code is now <div class='desc_html_aff'>  but your code dont work .

Answer (score 1):

The HTML string that you want to transform contains newline characters, which aren't matched by `.*?`. You can use `[\s\S]*?` instead:

```js
var desc_aff=$('.desc_html_aff').html().replace(/<ul(.*?)>([\s\S]*?)<\/ul>/gi,"!!");
console.log(desc_aff);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='desc_html_aff'>
sdsdfdfdgdsg
<ul class="pi_ul">
<li>abc</li>
<li>def </li>
<li>ererefe </li>
</ul>
wfwfwsfgdhfhfhdf
dgdfhfj
  </div>
```

Comment: var desc_aff=$('.desc_html_aff').html().replace(/<ul(.*?)>\n(*?)\n<\/ul>/gi,"!!");   dont work too

Comment: @webducommerce Did you try hitting the "Run code snippet" button ?